# given the index of an item in a view of a numpy array, find its index in the base array

Tags: arrays, numpy, view

Say `a` is a numpy array of shape `(N,)` and `b = a[k:l]`. I know that `x = b[i]`, is there a way to find `j` such that `x = a[j]` without knowing `k` and `l` and without searching `a` for `x`?

For instance `a = np.array([2,4,3,1,7])` and `b = a[1:4]`. I only have access to `b`, but would like to know what the index of `3` is in `a`, knowing that its index in `b` is `1`.

Of course I could access `a` by using `b.base`, and then search `a` for the item `3`, but I wondered wether there is a method attached to views which returns the index of an item in the base array.

Comment: This is quite hard to understand. Will you please provide a sample array and the output that you expect? We're not computers, so all these variable can be hard to reason about :)

Comment: There's nothing built into numpy arrays that will do this.  With my knowledge of shape, strides, and data-buffer pointer I could work this out for most cases, but it isn't a trivial task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hpaulj already has stated in the comments, there is no built in functionality to do so. But you can still compute the base's index from the size of the `dtype` and the byte offset between the base and the view. You can obtain the byte offset from the attribute `ndarray.__array_interface__['data'][0]`

```py
import numpy as np
import unittest

def baseIndex(array: np.ndarray, index: int) -> int:
    base = array.base
    if base is None:
        return index
    size = array.dtype.itemsize
    stride = array.strides[0] // size
    offset = (array.__array_interface__['data'][0] - base.__array_interface__['data'][0]) // size
    return offset + index * stride

a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
b = a
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1_simple(self):
        """b = a"""
        b = a
        i = 1
        j = baseIndex(b, i)
        self.assertEqual(a[j], b[i])
    
    def test_2_offset(self):
        """b = a[3:]"""
        b = a[3:]
        i = 1
        j = baseIndex(b, i)
        self.assertEqual(a[j], b[i])
    
    def test_3_strided(self):
        """b = a[1::2]"""
        b = a[1::2]
        i = 1
        j = baseIndex(b, i)
        self.assertEqual(a[j], b[i])
    
    def test_4_reverse_strided(self):
        """b = a[4::-2]"""
        b = a[4::-2]
        i = 1
        j = baseIndex(b, i)
        self.assertEqual(a[j], b[i])


unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Output:

```
test_1_simple (__main__.Test)
b = a ... ok
test_2_offset (__main__.Test)
b = a[3:] ... ok
test_3_strided (__main__.Test)
b = a[1::2] ... ok
test_4_reverse_strided (__main__.Test)
b = a[4::-2] ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

EDIT: I have now updated the function to handle cases where `b` is non-contiguous and/or reverse, thanks @Jérôme Richard for spotting that. Also, as @mozway states, `ndarray.__array_interface__` is an internal numpy detail that can change without notice, but as of now I don't see any other way to do so.

Comment: Nice, however this kind of approach should be used with care as the internal methods of numpy could change without warning.

Comment: That's the kind of calculation I had in mind.  Getting the `offset` is perhaps the most 'advanced' step.

Comment: Interesting strategy. However, it does not always work since the array can be *non-contiguous* or the array can even have a *negative stride*. You can try with `np.flip(np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]))` and the result is wrong.

Comment: @JérômeRichard You are correct, I forgot to consider such cases. I have updated the solution now.