# Converting subarray index into original array index with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

In this code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

def f(b, i):
  # calculate original index
  return j

a = np.random.rand((N, M))
b = a[:, m]
j = f(b, i)
assert b[i] == a[j]
```

I would like the function `f` to find an index, which satisfies the assertion at the last line. Indexing with `j` doesn't have to have `a[j]` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a sample array:

```
In [213]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [214]: a
Out[214]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

And `b` from that:

```
In [215]: b = a[:,2]
In [216]: b
Out[216]: array([ 2,  6, 10])
In [217]: b[1]
Out[217]: 6
```

All the `numpy` knows about `a` is in:

```
In [218]: a.__array_interface__
Out[218]: 
{'data': (51087664, False),
 'strides': None,         # a.strides is (32,8)
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 4),
 'version': 3}
```

`b` is a `view` of `a`, with the corresponding:

```
In [219]: b.__array_interface__
Out[219]: 
{'data': (51087680, False),
 'strides': (32,),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}
```

the `base` for `b` is the original `arange`:

```
In [221]: b.base
Out[221]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
In [222]: b.base.__array_interface__
Out[222]: 
{'data': (51087664, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (12,),
 'version': 3}
```

Your `f` could compare the `data` attribute of `b` with its base to get the `offset`, where `b` "starts"

```
 (51087680-51087664)/8
```

So `b` starts at

```
In [223]: (51087680-51087664)/8
Out[223]: 2.0
In [224]: b[0]
Out[224]: 2
In [225]: b.base[2]
Out[225]: 2
In [226]: a.ravel()[2]
Out[226]: 2
```

We can guess/deduce that since the strides of `b` is (32,), and `dtype` is `i8`, that the other strides of `a` is 8.

`b[1]` will be 32/8 beyond its start, or 4.

```
In [227]: b[1]
Out[227]: 6
In [228]: b.base[2+4]
Out[228]: 6
```

If we also deduce that `a` shape is (3,4)  (deduce the `4` for base length 12 and `b` shape of (3,)):

```
In [229]: np.unravel_index(6,(3,4))
Out[229]: (1, 2)
In [230]: a[1,2]
Out[230]: 6
```

I'll let you clean things up and decide for yourself whether these deductions and calculations are robust enough for your purposes.

### alt `a`

If `a` is its own `base` (not a `view` of something else), `b.base` will be `a` itself, and we don't have to make deductions about its `strides` and `shape`:

```
In [231]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4).copy()
In [232]: a.__array_interface__
Out[232]: 
{'data': (51778608, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 4),
 'version': 3}
In [233]: b = a[:,2]
In [234]: b.__array_interface__
Out[234]: 
{'data': (51778624, False),
 'strides': (32,),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}
In [235]: b.base
Out[235]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

There was similar question recently, and someone went to the work of packaging these calculations in a function.  I don't have a link to that, but it shouldn't be hard to find.  In any case, there isn't a simple `numpy` function call that will do this for you.

Here's the previous SO

[given the index of an item in a view of a numpy array, find its index in the base array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70544958/given-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-view-of-a-numpy-array-find-its-index-in-the-bas)